# List of methods: the methods are called always

Tags: ruby, list, methods

How can I make a list of methods without running it and using it latter?

For example

```
def somedef
  (anything)
end
a = [system("echo 'hello'"), 1, somedef]
```

After you type `a=[system("echo 'hello'"), 1, somedef]` you get `hello` and the result of `somedef` method. But I want to for example concatenate lists with methods within.

Comment: You don't need "Ruby" in the title since it's a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proc

```
a = [Proc.new {system("echo 'hello'")}, Proc.new {1}, Proc.new{somedef}]
```

Whenever you have to execute the methods execute the call method of the proc.

```
a[0].call #Output: hello
a[1].call #Output: 1
```

Comment: Which is best: method or Proc?

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, you can leave out the parentheses when calling a method. (I am quite surprised that you have never seen this before, as it is indeed quite common to do so.) Ergo, what you are doing is simply calling the methods.

If you want to get a reference to the method as an object, you can call the `method` method, which returns a `Method` object:

```
a = [system("echo 'hello'"), 1, method(:somedef)]
```

Comment: I came from python

Answer (score 1):

Using [method()](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html):

```
def hello
  system("echo 'hello'")
end
=> nil

a = [method(:hello), 1]
=> [#<Method: Object#hello>, 1]

foo[0].call
hello
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your needs are you can also just save symbols and then send them to the appropriate object when necessary. For example:

```
def some_def 
   ...
 end 
a = [:some_def]
self.send(a[0])
```

It's just an alternative to the other good answers on this page. It's a weak contract (you have to know that the object you are sending this messages to will respond to them) but it may be enough for some scenarios.